# Why I get error 'Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.' on submit form Paypal?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="askerov.ibraqim@mail.ru">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="213">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="21.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/cart">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/cart">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/cart">
<button class="checkout black-btn" id="checkout" name="submit" type="submit">Checkout</button>
```

Why I get error 'Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later.' on submit form  Paypal?